# グローバル変数としてArrayListを使う

Tags: android, java

学習中の初心者です。
Realmで保存するシンプルなデータ（Id, String contents）を、アプリ起動時に読み込んでグローバル変数として保存しておき、複数のActivityで利用したいと考えています。

グローバル変数の準備として、
Manifest に `<application android:name=".ThisApp"` を入れ、
ThisApp に下記のように入れました。

```
public class ThisApp extends Application {
//グローバルに使用する変数
public ArrayList<String> GlobalArrayList;
//初期化メソッド
public void GlobalArrayList(){
    GlobalArrayList = new GlobalArrayList<String>();
}
```

そしてこのグローバル変数にRealmからデータを入力するのはMainActivityで行おうとして、まずMainActivityの変数定義に `ThisApp GlobalArrayList;` を設定し、同じくMainActivityで読み込んだRealmResoltsをセットしようとして、下記のように入れました。

```
//Realmの設定
Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
mRealmResults = mRealm.where(jobCategory.class).findAll();
mRealm.addChangeListener(mRealmListener);
// グローバル変数の取得、入力
GlobalArrayList= (TaskApp) this.getApplication();
GlobalArrayList.GlobalArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < mCategoryRealmResults.size(); i++) {
    GlobalArrayList.add(mRealmResults.get(i).getContents());
    }
```

しかし最後の「GlobalArrayList.add(～）」の「add」が赤字になってしまいます。グローバル変数のArrayList.addというのは使えないのでしょうか。または、初心者なので、どこか文法が間違えているのでしょうか。

Comment: クラス定義では`ThisApp`となっていますが、`getApplication()`の箇所では`TaskApp`になっています。正しいほうに回答を修正してください。 また、初期化メソッドの箇所で`new GlobalArrayList<String>()`となっていますが、`ArrayList`の間違いでしょうか？または`GlobalArrayList`というクラスを定義しているのですか？

Comment: 回答を修正してください。->質問を修正してください。 の間違いでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 質問の回答

使用したいArrayListは`ThisApp`クラスの`GlobalArrayList`というインスタンス変数です。
`ThisApp`のインスタンスは`GlobalArrayList`という変数に代入しています。

したがって、
`GlobalArrayList.GlobalArrayList.add(mRealmResults.get(i).getContents());`
とすればいいです。

### 変数名／メソッド名の命名について

`GlobalArrayList`という名前を複数使用しているので混乱しているのだと思います。

```java
//グローバルに使用する変数
public ArrayList<String> GlobalArrayList;
```

変数名には何を格納しているのかわかるような名前にすると読みやすくなります。
ここで何を格納してようとしているのかわかりませんが、RealmResultsのcontentsを格納しているので、例えば`contentsList`のような名前が良いです。

```java
//初期化メソッド
public void GlobalArrayList(){
```

初期化メソッドは`init***`という名前にするとわかりやすくなります。

```java
// グローバル変数の取得、入力
GlobalArrayList= (TaskApp) this.getApplication();
```

ここで取得しているのはApplicationなので`app`等の名前が良いです。

因みに、Javaでは変数名とメソッド名の先頭は小文字にするのが習慣です。

以上を踏まえてコードを書き直すと次のようになります。

```java
public class ThisApp extends Application {
    //グローバルに使用する変数
    public ArrayList<String> contentsList;
    //初期化メソッド
    public void initContentsList(){
        contentsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

```java
app = (ThisApp) this.getApplication();
app.initContentsList();
for (int i = 0; i < mCategoryRealmResults.size(); i++) {
    app.contentsList.add(mRealmResults.get(i).getContents());
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
返信が遅くなってしまいましたが、教えていただいたことを復習しながら完成させることができました。
また、命名ルールについてもしっかり学習するようにします。
コンストラクタやインスタンスについて理解が浅いのがわかり、そこから復習しながら学習してみます。

Answer (score 1):

`ThisApp GlobalArrayList`と定義しているので、`GlobalArrayList.GlobalArrayList.add(mRealmResults.get(i).getContents());`とする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
自分で定義しておいて混乱していました。

Answer (score 1):

基本的な回答については @tag1216 さんの回答の通りです。

補足ですが、複数のActivityでの利用を想定しているのであれば、`contentsList`の初期化は可能な限り`Application`クラス（今回では`ThisApp`クラス）の`onCreate()`の中で行うのが安全でしょう。

アプリの規模が大きくなったり仕様の変更があった際、必ずしも`MainActivity`からアプリがスタートするわけではなくなる場合があるからです。（ウィジェットからの起動、外部サービスからのスキーマ起動など）

おそらく`MainActivity`以外は「すでに`contentsList`が初期化されている」前提の実装になるかと思いますので、もし`MainActivity`からアプリがスタートしなかった場合に`initContentsList ()`が実行されず、`contentsList`を使っている行で`NullPointerException`が発生し、アプリが強制終了してしまいます。

Comment: 必ず必要なThisAppクラスのonCreateに初期化メソッドを入れておくわけですね。ありがとうございます。グローバル変数のように使っていきたいのは、今後複雑なものも組めるようになりたいためでしたので、大変勉強になりました！